# How to decide whether if run a function by user in script

Tags: python-2.7

I got two function in a script like :

def a():
print a

def b():
print b

How to decide whether if run the function 'b' by user?
Thanks a advance

Comment: You want to call the function 'B' for specific user?

Comment: yes...................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#At starting of script take the username as input

name = raw_input("Enter Your Name : ")
name.lower() #To make input name lowercase

if name == 'bob': #name for which you have to call b
   b()
else:
   a()
```